Reproject shapefile from WGS 1984 WKID 4326 to Moon 2000 south pole stereographic
I have a shapefile of a road path that was made on a web-based GIS that is in GCS WGS 1984. To edit in my GIS I want to reproject into Moon 2000 South Pole Stereographic (https://epsg.io/103878).
I have tried using the following code:
import geopandas as gpd
from pyproj import CRS

#Load shapefile
 shp = "test_road.shp"

 #Define proj 
string moon_proj = "+proj=stere +lat_0=90 +lon_0=0 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +R=1737400 +units=m +no_defs +type=crs"`

#create CRS
crs_moon = CRS.from_string(moon_proj)

#Reproject
shp_reproj = shp.to_crs(crs_moon)

This isn't working, anyone know how I can reproject?

Maybe try +lat_0=-90 rather than +90?

You absolutely don't want to reproject from a terrestrial datum to a lunar one (no such transform available). This is one of the few cases where you want to clobber the existing geographic coordinate system before projecting.

What do you mean by not working? Do you get error messages?

I do not know if the results from the following workflow makes sense, but at least it seems to be possible to force Proj to make the transformation. This is tested with Proj Rel. 9.4.0, March 1st, 2024 on Windows (OSGeo4W).
Check what projinfo says about your transformation.
projinfo -s epsg:4326 -t "+proj=stere +lat_0=90 +lon_0=0 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +R=1737400 +units=m +no_defs +type=crs"
createOperations() failed with: Source and target ellipsoid do not belong to the same celestial body (Moon vs Earth). You may override this check by setting the PROJ_IGNORE_CELESTIAL_BODY environment variable to YES.

Ok, it does not want to convert data between Earth and Moon. Try the override:
set PROJ_IGNORE_CELESTIAL_BODY=YES

Now one operation is found:
projinfo -s epsg:4326 -t "+proj=stere +lat_0=90 +lon_0=0 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +R=1737400 +units=m +no_defs +type=crs"
Candidate operations found: 1
-------------------------------------
Operation No. 1:

unknown id, Ballpark geographic offset from WGS 84 to unknown + unknown, unknown accuracy, World, has ballpark transformation

PROJ string:
+proj=pipeline
  +step +proj=axisswap +order=2,1
  +step +proj=unitconvert +xy_in=deg +xy_out=rad
  +step +proj=stere +lat_0=90 +lon_0=0 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +R=1737400

WKT2:2019 string:
CONCATENATEDOPERATION["Ballpark geographic offset from WGS 84 to unknown + unknown",
    SOURCECRS[
        GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
            ENSEMBLE["World Geodetic System 1984 ensemble",
                MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (Transit)"],
                MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G730)"],
                MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G873)"],
                MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G1150)"],
                MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G1674)"],
                MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G1762)"],
                MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G2139)"],
                ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                    LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
                ENSEMBLEACCURACY[2.0]],
            PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
                ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
            CS[ellipsoidal,2],
                AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
                    ORDER[1],
                    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
                AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
                    ORDER[2],
                    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
            ID["EPSG",4326]]],
    TARGETCRS[
        PROJCRS["unknown",
            BASEGEOGCRS["unknown",
                DATUM["unknown",
                    ELLIPSOID["unknown",1737400,0,
                        LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                            ID["EPSG",9001]]]],
                PRIMEM["Reference meridian",0,
                    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
                        ID["EPSG",9122]]]],
            CONVERSION["unknown",
                METHOD["Polar Stereographic (variant A)",
                    ID["EPSG",9810]],
                PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",90,
                    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
                    ID["EPSG",8801]],
                PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",0,
                    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
                    ID["EPSG",8802]],
                PARAMETER["Scale factor at natural origin",1,
                    SCALEUNIT["unity",1],
                    ID["EPSG",8805]],
                PARAMETER["False easting",0,
                    LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
                    ID["EPSG",8806]],
                PARAMETER["False northing",0,
                    LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
                    ID["EPSG",8807]]],
            CS[Cartesian,2],
                AXIS["(E)",south,
                    MERIDIAN[90,
                        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
                            ID["EPSG",9122]]],
                    ORDER[1],
                    LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                        ID["EPSG",9001]]],
                AXIS["(N)",south,
                    MERIDIAN[180,
                        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
                            ID["EPSG",9122]]],
                    ORDER[2],
                    LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                        ID["EPSG",9001]]]]],
    STEP[
        COORDINATEOPERATION["Ballpark geographic offset from WGS 84 to unknown",
            SOURCECRS[
                GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
                    ENSEMBLE["World Geodetic System 1984 ensemble",
                        MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (Transit)"],
                        MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G730)"],
                        MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G873)"],
                        MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G1150)"],
                        MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G1674)"],
                        MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G1762)"],
                        MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G2139)"],
                        ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
                        ENSEMBLEACCURACY[2.0]],
                    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
                        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
                    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
                        AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
                            ORDER[1],
                            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
                        AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
                            ORDER[2],
                            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
                    ID["EPSG",4326]]],
            TARGETCRS[
                GEOGCRS["unknown",
                    DATUM["unknown",
                        ELLIPSOID["unknown",1737400,0,
                            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                                ID["EPSG",9001]]]],
                    PRIMEM["Reference meridian",0,
                        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
                            ID["EPSG",9122]]],
                    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
                        AXIS["longitude",east,
                            ORDER[1],
                            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
                                ID["EPSG",9122]]],
                        AXIS["latitude",north,
                            ORDER[2],
                            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
                                ID["EPSG",9122]]]]],
            METHOD["Geographic2D offsets",
                ID["EPSG",9619]],
            PARAMETER["Latitude offset",0,
                ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
                ID["EPSG",8601]],
            PARAMETER["Longitude offset",0,
                ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
                ID["EPSG",8602]]]],
    STEP[
        CONVERSION["unknown",
            METHOD["Polar Stereographic (variant A)",
                ID["EPSG",9810]],
            PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",90,
                ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
                ID["EPSG",8801]],
            PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",0,
                ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
                ID["EPSG",8802]],
            PARAMETER["Scale factor at natural origin",1,
                SCALEUNIT["unity",1],
                ID["EPSG",8805]],
            PARAMETER["False easting",0,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
                ID["EPSG",8806]],
            PARAMETER["False northing",0,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
                ID["EPSG",8807]]]],
    USAGE[
        SCOPE["unknown"],
        AREA["World"],
        BBOX[-90,-180,90,180]]]

Test with gdaltransform. Make sure that the PROJ_IGNORE_CELESTIAL_BODY=YES environmental variable is still set.
gdaltransform -s_srs epsg:4326 -t_srs "+proj=stere +lat_0=90 +lon_0=0 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +R=1737400 +units=m +no_defs +type=crs"
Enter X Y [Z [T]] values separated by space, and press Return.
27 60
422696.868246176 -829589.314264072 0

Try if geopandas and pyproj are also checking the existence of PROJ_IGNORE_CELESTIAL_BODY=YES
